# suppress Toast when setting AlarmClock

Tags: android

im programming an android app which sets my AlarmClock.

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Google Cal Alarm");
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, l.getHours());
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, l.getMinutes());
```

the problem is, that I'm doing that in a background service,
but the AlarmClock pops up toasts every time the Clock is set.

Can i prevent that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for `AlarmClock`...

> The AlarmClock provider contains an Intent action and extras that can be used to **start an Activity to set a new alarm in an alarm clock application.** Applications that wish to receive the ACTION_SET_ALARM Intent should create an activity to handle the Intent that requires the permission com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM. **Applications that wish to create a new alarm should use Context.startActivity() so that the user has the option of choosing which alarm clock application to use.**

This suggests to me that `AlarmClock` is designed to be used in a UI context. Is there a reason why you are using it rather than [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)?

Comment: Hm I don't know when to use AlarmManager but thanks for the info